# change sql query to NOT return same value multiple times in a JOIN

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I have the following sql query

```
SELECT "Item"."id",
       "Item"."name",
       "Item"."active",
       "Item"."vendible",
       "Item"."purchasable",
       "Item"."type",
       "Item"."listNetPrice",
       "vendors"."id" AS "vendors.id",
       "vendors->PartnerItems"."createdAt" AS "vendors.PartnerItems.createdAt",
       "vendors->PartnerItems"."updatedAt" AS "vendors.PartnerItems.updatedAt",
       "vendors->PartnerItems"."ItemId" AS "vendors.PartnerItems.ItemId",
       "vendors->PartnerItems"."PartnerId" AS "vendors.PartnerItems.PartnerId",
       "VatKey"."id" AS "VatKey.id",
       "VatKey"."key" AS "VatKey.key"
FROM "overseer"."Item" AS "Item"
  INNER JOIN ("overseer"."PartnerItems" AS "vendors->PartnerItems"
  INNER JOIN "overseer"."Partner" AS "vendors" ON "vendors"."id" = "vendors->PartnerItems"."PartnerId")
          ON "Item"."id" = "vendors->PartnerItems"."ItemId"
         AND ("vendors"."id" = 1
          OR "vendors"."id" = 2)
  LEFT OUTER JOIN "overseer"."VatKey" AS "VatKey" ON "Item"."VatKeyId" = "VatKey"."id"
WHERE ("Item"."name" ilike '%%' OR "Item"."tariffNo" ilike '%%')
ORDER BY "Item"."id" ASC LIMIT 5 OFFSET 0
```

which gives the following results

[image: query result image]

My Items can have many Partners, (with many-to-many association) if they are only associated to one I don't have a problem, but if a single item has more partners the above problem occurs. The same item gets selected multiple times, I only want them to be shown once, doesn't matter how many partners they have.

Comment: What would you have it return instead? I have two addresses, a work address and a home address. Select me inner join addresses and you get two rows - same me in both, and two different addresses! Youre saying "I only want to see one of you" -- but which one?

Comment: Using `a->b` as an alias does not make your query easy to understand.